# What is causing that nasty horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: css

I am wrapping up a few touches on a site and notice that something is forcing the horizontal scrollbar to appear way beyond the container boundaries [here](http://www.ideapeoplesite.com/projectpath/jrs/waterfalls.html).

I have Firebugged it to death, but still can't figure out what the offending party is. I offer quick kudos to anyone that can tell me what is wrong here.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not seeing it in Firefox nor IE8

Comment: @duralai: Nor I. @fmz: Which container are you using scrolling *on*? I see nothing that scrolls. Resizing my browser generates a horizontal scrollbar on the bottom of the browser itself (thanks to your fixed-width page setup), but nowhere else.

Comment: It was showing up in Firefox. I added the following and it is now gone:

html {overflow-x: hidden; }

Comment: When posting questions like this, don't post "What is wrong here" because we might see multiple problems, rather tackle the question directly by asking something like "How do I remove the horizontal scroll bar" or "How do I check for an element causing the overflow"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone else posted an answer earlier and then withdrew it. It was close but not all the way there.

Here is what ended up solving the problem:

```
html 
 {
 height: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```

Comment: this is a solution, but what causes it?

Comment: Still only a solution, still no idea what causes the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with the margin on the #container div.

When I Inspect Element on Google Chrome and change the margin style to `margin: 0;` the scroll bar goes away.

try adding: `padding: 0px;` to the style. it stays centered and the scroll bar goes away.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Comment: you must have added the html {overflow-x: hidden; } when i was messing with the chrome inspect element tool. glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Something important to check for in addition to padding and margin is a border. A border will add width to your element.

```
border: none;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
```

That should fix it